# Why is the -- operator not subtracting from the value when executed?

Tags: c, decrement, postfix-operator

Why is the decrement operator `--` not bringing the value down by 1 when executed?

```
int a = 20;
int c ;

c = a--;
```

Inspecting the value of `c` now, it should be 19, yet it comes out as 20. What am I missing?

Comment: You might want to print `a` as well: `c` has the value of `a` before decrementing. Decrementing affects only `a`. If you want `c` to be one less than `a` without changing `a`, just use `c = a - 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you're using is called a `postfix` operator. It will get executed [decrement the value] after the assignment `=` operator has finished its execution with the *existing* value.

To be clear, in case of post decrement, the `..--` operator is evaluated and the decrement is scheduled once the other evaluations including that operand are finished. It means, the *existing value of the operand is used in the other evaluation* [in `=`] and then *the value is decreased*.

If you want, try printing the value of `a` itself. It will print the decremented value.

---

EDIT:

If my choice of words in my answer created any confusions, for the reference, from the `c99` standard, chapter 6.5.2.4, [emphasis mine]

> [For increment] The result of the postfix ++ operator is the ***value of the operand***. ***After*** the result is obtained, the value of the operand is ***incremented***  [......]
>
> The postfix -- operator is analogous to the postfix ++ operator, except that the value of the operand is decremented (that is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is subtracted from it).

Comment: Is there any practical use for a postfix? when would it be beneficial for the calculation to be done after the program has been evaluated...

Comment: @StevieMack yes, obviously !!! Think of a counter in `loop`ing conditions.

Comment: @StevieMack also, think of this `*destination++ = *source++`. maybe you can roll your own string copy function with this. :-)

Comment: @StevieMack - `Is there any practical use for a postfix?` - Its just a style. Normally one would not want to write `i=i-1` for pre-increment or type an extra line for post like `some_statement; i=i-1`.

Comment: WOW !!! and the reason for downvote, please? [ @ dear downvoter]

Comment: `after the assignment = operator has finished its execution.` As per the standard `In an expression that is evaluated more than once during the execution of a program, unsequenced and indeterminately sequenced evaluations of its subexpressions need not be performed consistently in different evaluations

    (§1.9/15) The value computations of the operands of an operator are sequenced before the value computation of the result of the operator.
`3

Comment: @StevieMack Please go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points - the above answer is not infallible.

Comment: @al-Acme I'm not too sure what you're trying to say. I never said something about _one_ expression getting evaluated more than once. What i mentioned is which value will be used while performing the decrement operation.

Comment: I now see that this question has answers, however, I simply did not have the language necessary to find this. If a person does not know the word for something it makes it difficult.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Do't care about those downVotes :D Everything will become good at some time!

Comment: @Rizier123 Thanks. Hoping the same. Cheers Mate !!

Answer (score 1):

`a--` is Post-Decrement, what you need `--a` Pre-Decrement. Please read Increment and decrement operators on [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators)

> The following C code fragment illustrates the difference between the pre and post increment and decrement operators:

```
int  x;
int  y;

// Increment operators
x = 1;
y = ++x;    
// x is now 2, y is also 2
y = x++;
// x is now 3, y is 2

// Decrement operators
x = 3;
y = x--;    
// x is now 2, y is 3
y = --x;    
// x is now 1, y is also 1
```

Comment: shouldn't it read `decrement`?

Answer (score 0):

you should use --a (pre decrement operator), you are using post decrement operator a--

The result of the postfix -- operator is the value of the operand. As a side effect, the
value of the operand object is decremented (that is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is
subtracted to it).

Answer (score 0):

You are using the post decrement. Post decrement means first use the value in a variable or 
anything then decrement the value in the variable. So in this case first value of `a` will assigned to `c`. And the decrement is  done. You can check printing the value of `a`.

Comment: How come another answer with same error? `..--` is ___decrement___, not increment.